# Vaadin Table showing NOTHING

Tags: vaadin

I have a vaadin table where I use certain filters for filtering, just like in the addressbook example (+ I added some more). Sometimes now it occurs that the table looks empty with NO HEADERS.

There were headers and items before. It is not just that the items are all filtered out, when debugging I see that the container the table is attached to still contains the items, and filtered is also not empty. Has anyone  overcome that problem already?

Any hints how to solve are very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using Vaadin 6.7.0. That version [has a regression](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/7731) where a Javascript error occurs when adding an item to an empty table that has an explicit column with set. If you append `?debug` to the URL, you will see the error in the debug window. That bug is resolved in Vaadin 6.7.1 which has already been released.

Comment: that solved the problem. Error before solving was:    
`JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'A' of null`